# How to use Flutter's Widget Inspector in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, widget, flutter, macos-sierra, inspector

How do you use the Flutter Widget Inspector [introduced](https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-17/) in VSCode and now [enabled](https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-20/)? When I debug the app from the IDE or Terminal, nothing happens when I click on any widget in the iOS simulator. I could not find any info on VSCode from [Google](https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/inspector).

I am on MacOS Sierra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When debugging, run command **Flutter: Inspect Widget**, then click on the UI/Widget, it will auto lead you to the code which generates the widget. It only works in debugging mode and the command is not available until the app is loaded in debug.
[image]

Comment: Thank you - my problem was debugging from Terminal and thinking VSCode could attach automatically, it doesn't appear to be the case. It must be debugged within the IDE.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be only working when you debug from IDE for now. Maybe that's something Dart/Flutter plugin can be improved in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately this command can only run when VS Code has a connection to the debugger. This means you either need to launch it from VS Code or use the `Debug: Attach to Flutter Process` command.

Generally, I would recommend always debugging from VS Code rather than the terminal, as there are other features you'll miss (like hot-reload-on-save) if you don't :-)

Answer (score 9):

As of v2.24, the Dart extension for VS Code has integration with the Dart DevTools. This has much better inspector functionality than the original **Inspect Widget** command mentioned by stt106's.

With a debugging session active, open the command palette and find the DevTools command.

[image]

The first time you run this you'll may be prompted to activate or upgrade.

[image]

DevTools will then launch in your browser and connect to your debug session.

[image]

There's more info on the functionality of Dart's DevTools [in the DevTools docs](https://flutter.github.io/devtools/).

Answer (score 0):

**Updated method:**

As of Dart Code (VS code extension) version 2.24.0,  The 'Flutter: Inspect Widget' command was replaced with DevTools. (at the time of writing this, the latest version is 3.36.0. To get to the Inspect Widget from the command pallet with >Flutter: Open DevTools or >Dart: Open DevTools, requires several steps.

Here's a quicker way:

```
  Click the debug (bug) button from the side menu and Select Run and Debug or press f5
```

The Widget inspector will open automatically.
[image: Screenshot of side menu]

Screenshot of emulator using the Flutter Widget inspector
[image]